# Filter secret objects by label in client-go

Tags: api, kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to get some secret objects from my cluster using the `k8s` `go` client library as follows

```
secret, err := clientset.CoreV1().Secrets("mynamespace").Get("name-of-my-secret", metav1.GetOptions{})
```

This worked well as long as I had to get just one object.

I have a case now where I need to fetch several such secret objects, however this now has to be done based on labels. (i.e. fetch all such secret objects matching the `foo=someprovider.someurl.com/path1=value1` label)

I don't see however in the relevant [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#GetOptions) a way to pass label selectors to the `GetOptions` struct that I assume performs such kind of filtering.

Any suggestions on how to select (potentially multiple) such resources based on labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clientset.CoreV1().Secrets("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: "k8s-app=kube-proxy"})
```